# Why does compiler gives this exception

Tags: java, guava

I want to check whether a file is exist or not. To do so, I have `usedPreconditions.checkArgument()` method with `File.exists()` method. However, the compiler gives `IllegalArgumentException`. Why does compiler gives this exception?

```
File fileIn = new File(filename); 
Preconditions.checkArgument( fileIn.exists() != false );
```

Comment: Quite possibly caused by a faulty filename - but we can't know unless you post more code.

Comment: there no more code just them. all is i have in method is given.

Comment: So where does the filename come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, a few things to note. First, compilers do not give Exceptions, they give compilation errors - what you are experiencing is at runtime, not compile-time. Second, `fileIn.exists() != false` is equivalent to `fileIn.exists()`, which is easier to read.

The actual problem you're receiving is because your condition is false - which implies in your case that the file doesn't exist. We can't help more with that unless you post more code, but it's pretty self-explanatory. See documentation on the `checkArgument()` method [here](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkArgument(boolean))

Answer (score 1):

It's not the compiler, it's the checkArgument method itself.
In documentation (https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java) it says it is supposed to throw IllegalArgumentException if the expression is false.

So Your file does not exist